# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: get file from a folder macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I copied the path link and used it in my code, but I'm still getting the error. Below is my code I am trying to run and the path.

```
import os
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir("Macintosh HD/Users/engpen/downloads/prank")
    print(file_list)
```

Comment: But do you have the subdirectory "Macintosh HD" in the directory where you run your program? And do you have user 'engpen'?

Comment: The safest thing to do is to use the full path name of a file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use. Then check step by step whether your path is correct.

```
os.path.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing a bit here. The path most likely should be `/Users/engpen/...`.
Thus try:

```
import os
def rename_files():
   file_list = os.listdir("/Users/engpen/downloads/prank")
   print(file_list)
```